# Are questions on copyright on topic?

Tags: discussion

I was going to ask about using an excerpt from a classical piece that was not in public domain in a song was on topic. In more detail, my question was going to be about how much I would have to change in order to steer clear from a copyright claim if that would be a problem. I don't know if that would fit in this community, so if it doesn't, could I be directed to where I could ask this question and have it be on topic?

Comment: It's worth noting that the world of music copyright has been in transition the last few years, with some record labels blocking the use of even just tiny fragments of their music in educational YouTube videos, and also a lot of controversy about a few recent court cases in the USA where songwriters have been convicted of plagiarizing songs that are only vaguely similar to their work. See e.g; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ytoUuO-qvg

Comment: @YourUncleBob And at a frightening pace, too. Lately, seems all the music educators have said something on this lawsuit or that one, and from what I can tell, there seems to be a surge in copyright disputes recently. Good point.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, legal questions are off-topic on this site in general as stated in the [FAQ](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The reason is that it's typically out of the knowledge domain of a typical musician and even if one knows their local copyright laws, they may vary depending on where exactly you live.

The Law SE may cater to these types of questions and already seem to have a trove of [music related copyright questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music).