# The Copyrights tag

Tags: discussion, tags, scope, close-reasons, topics

There are a dozen or so questions with the [copyrights](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyrights) tag, many currently pending closure.

Legal issues are off-topic on SE: Music Practice & Theory (see: [Are questions on copyright on topic?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/are-questions-on-copyright-on-topic)).

Questions about copyright are *necessarily** questions on legal issues.

So, shouldn't the [copyrights](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyrights) tag either be removed, or at least have its [Tag Info](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/are-questions-on-copyright-on-topic) clearly marked as "Please do not ask questions about copyright here." or similar?

---

<sup>*</sup> 
Or are there *possibly*† some questions that should have the [copyrights](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyrights) tag, and yet could still somehow be on-topic for SE: Music Practice & Theory?

---

<sup>†</sup> 
As seen in the below "duplicate" post on this exact topic (that is obviously better, more thorough, more researched, and goes into more detail, etc.  <sub><sup>but got stuck in the space-time continuum</sup></sub> .)
... there *is* at least one good/maybe-okay question that should have the [copyrights](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyrights) tag, and *could* be considered to be on-topic, as well as some borderline questions.
[Legal question prohibition vs. copyright questions and the [copyright] tag: Close them all and remove the tag](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/legal-question-prohibition-vs-copyright-questions-and-the-copyright-tag-clos)

Comment: Well, this is upsetting. I voted to close those questions after spending several hours researching and writing a Meta post like this one, which, bizarrely, seems not to have actually posted. Anyway....

Comment: ... yes, the questions should all be closed and the tag removed — which is hard, so in the interim the tag wiki should be updated to say "do not use".

Comment: Okay, I see what happened to my post. It's now there, closed as duplicate, but contains some additional information on this topic.

Comment: @Aaron I might have some how managed to somehow post my question before you, but your question is obviously better, more thorough, more researched etc.  Why did your question get closed? - my question is the dupe

Comment: @Aaron I saw your 6 retags, and close votes, agreed and voted to close, then wondered why the tag existed at all and posted the above.  I didn't mean to copy your idea.

Comment: I created my post several hours before yours, but it failed to post (I just discovered). I found the problem, posted, then closed it as a duplicate, because your post covers the question more than adequately and far more concisely. My bruised pride would appreciate a link from your footnote to my post, since it addresses the issue of "maybe okay" copyright questions.

Comment: I saw your close votes not long after you made them, which was gratifying. And I see now another voter has joined us.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to retag current questions and remove the tag *unless* the tag usage can be rewritten to cover an area clearly within scope. I think previously this came up and there were some suggestions for uses in scope, but I'd need to dig that up.

I also recommend closing questions that are clearly about off-topic copyright legal or business  questions.

Comment: I have closed obvious ones. I see you have deleted the ones which really needed deleting - the others can probably stay (we could mark as historical)